# xlwt writing excel file python problem

Tags: python, xlwt

So I have to two separate lists of data, wordlist and digitlist. And both sets have related sets of data so wordlist[1] is related to digitlist[1]. The data sets are shown below:

```
seglist = ['aaa111', 'bbb222', 'ccc333']
wordlist = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
digitlist = ['111', '222', '333']
```

I'm tryin to create a a new sheet for each set of data, and write the wordlist in the first column and digitlist in the second column of the sheet. Now the following code works when I only include one set of data:

```
for i in range(len(seglist)):
p = str(i)
ws = w.add_sheet(p)
for i, cell in enumerate(wordlist[i]):
    ws.write(i,0,cell)
```

But when I try to add second data set it gives me and error. I think the problem is that the excel worksheets can't be written on twice. So does that mean I have to reopen the newly excel file, and then reformat it?  Also, does anyone have any ideas on how to write simultaneously with both sets of data on the excel spreadsheet?

```
for i in range(len(seglist)):
p = str(i)
ws = w.add_sheet(p)
for i, cell in enumerate(wordlist[i]):
    ws.write(i,0,cell)
    for i, cell in enumerate(digitlist[i]):
        ws.write(i,1,cell)
Exception: Attempt to overwrite cell: sheetname=u'0' rowx=0 colx=1
```

Also the number of items listed in each data set may not be the same.

Comment: Your wordlist/digitlist examples  are very confusing. You show each as a list of strings. However your two code snippets appear to treat each of them as a list of lists of something, and you did not contradict the assumption that @sean made to that effect. Do you want to iterate over the characters? Please change your examples, use e.g. `wordlist = ['abc, 'def', 'ghi']` (and similar for digitlist) -- so that we can relate the desired output *unambiguously* to the input -- and say exactly what output you expect to appear in cells A1:B2 on the first and second sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your two pieces of code (as shown in your question) have any chance of working, because (1) the indentation is stuffed up (2) you use the variable `i` in *every* `for` loop.

Fix the indentation and replace the loop variables with *meaningful* names, like `sheet_index`, `row_index`, col_index` (or sheetx/rowx/colx if you prefer fewer keystrokes).

What is `seglist`?

"""Excel spreadsheets can't be written on twice""" -- not so. By default, `xlwt` prevents you from writing on the same *cell* twice. Empirical evidence is that 99.99% of the time, the cause is woolly logic. People who need to overwrite cells (*not* required in your above task) can override the overwrite check.

So, putting it all together, the following code implements what I understand out of """I'm tryin to create a a new sheet for each set of data, and write the wordlist in the first column and digitlist in the second column of the sheet."""

```
assert len(wordlist) == len(digitlist)
for sheetx in xrange(len(seglist)):
    ws = w.add_sheet(str(sheeetx))
    assert len(wordlist[sheetx]) == len(digitlist[sheetx])
    for rowx, values in enumerate(zip(wordlist[sheetx], digitlist[sheetx]):
        for colx, value in enumerate(values):
            ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
```

If any `assert` triggers, you need to examine your data ...

**Update** in response to info about ragged data:

```
assert len(wordlist) == len(digitlist) == len(seglist))
for sheetx in xrange(len(seglist)):
    ws = w.add_sheet(str(sheeetx))
    for colx, values in enumerate((wordlist[sheetx], digitlist[sheetx])):
        for rowx, value in enumerate(values):
            ws.write(rowx, colx, value)
```

Comment: This is not the complete solution, because if one set of data has less items than the other, then it only writes up to the point of the number of items in the shorter list.  So if wordlist[1] has 3 items, and digitlist[1] has 5 items, the excel file will write only 3 items in digitlist[1].

Comment: @kr21: You should edit your question to include the new information that the list lengths are not equal.

Comment: @kr21: Do you have a complete solution now?

Comment: Yes, your updated answer is the complete solution, thanks alot!

Comment: @kr21: In that case, please "accept" my answer by clicking on the big tick to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that in your second loop you are continually hitting the same cells over and over again.

That is to say assuming your data looks something like this data:

```
wordlist = [['cat','feline','kitty'], ['dog','canine','puppy']]
digitlist = [[3,7,9000],[17,8,4000]]
```

When you hit `wordlist`, you write:

```
Sheet0
    Row0
    -----
    cat
    feline
    kitty
Sheet1
    Row0
    -----
    dog
    canine
    puppy
```

When you add the iteration over `digitlist` into the mix, then you are running over *all* of the entries in `digitlist[i]` for every entry in `wordlist[i]`.

So your program writes out "cat" into Row0, Cell0 [that is, `(0,0)`] and then writes out 3, 7 and 9000 into `(0,1)`, `(1,1)` and `(1,2)`.  Then your program writes out "feline" into `(1,0)` ... *and then tries to write out 3, 7 and 9000 into `(0,1)`, `(1,1)` and `(1,2)` all over again.*  Also, the inner `i` shadows the outer `i` ... if it didn't, (if you used `ii` for you inner loop), then you would be trying to write out 17, 8 and 4000 into `(0,1)`, `(1,1)` and `(1,2)` ... which may not be what you want at all.

If what you want to do is merge the word and digit lists and write them out next to each other then try [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) instead.

```
for i in range(len(wordlist)):
    merged = zip(wordlist[i], digitlist[i])
    cells = range(len(merged[0])) # Assumes no ragged arrays
    for row in range(len(merged)):
        for col in cells:
            ws.write(row, col, merged[row][col])
```

Comment: Is there any way to isolate each item in the merged list, and print them out on the worksheet?

Comment: @kr21 - `zip` does that for you.  It takes `['dog', 'canine', 'puppy']` and `[17, 8, 4000]` and returns `[('dog', 17), ('canine', 8), ('puppy', 4000)]`